# Can I use the sd card from my Raspberry Pi 3 in my Raspberry Pi 4 for Kali Linux?

Tags: sd-card, pi-4

My Raspberry Pi 3 model B recently stopped working and I am planning on getting a Raspberry Pi 4. I was wondering if I could use the sd card with Kali Linux from the Raspberry Pi 3 in my Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: It depends on the Kali version. Might be done, check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243520) out.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The RPi4B needs the latest bootcode, kernel and firmware (built after June 2019) or it won't boot.

You'll need https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-2019.4/kali-linux-2019.4-light-armhf.img.xz (and will probably need to check with the Kali developers to confirm that works on a RPi4B).